# varios botones submit dentro de un mismo formulario

Tags: php, formularios

tengo este formulario que deberia ir a paypal al pulsar el boton paypal, y deberia eliminar un item cuando le doy al boton eliminar.
Pero al estar dentro del mismo formulario al darle al boton eliminar me va a la pagina de paypal. ¿como puedo solucionar esto? El codigo
es una simplificacion del que yo tengo en realidad (para no complicarlo demasiado) y viene a ser una tabla con varios items donde se puede eliminar cada uno de ellos con el boton eliminar, o bien pagar todos los items con el boton paypal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $items = array("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4");
    if (isset($_POST["eliminar"]))
    {
        echo ("Articulo Eliminado");
    }
    ?>
        <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sb-pwrdu1932120@business.example.com" />
    <?php 
    $i=0;
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            echo("<input type='hidden' name='quantity_".$i."' value='1'/>");
            echo("<input type='hidden' name='item_name_".$i."' value='".$item."'/>");
            echo("<input type='hidden' name='item_number_".$i."' value='".$item."' />");
            echo("<input type='hidden' name='amount_".$i."' value='1' />");
            echo("<input type='submit' name='eliminar' value='Eliminar'><br>");
            $i++;
        }
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://infrangible-discoun.000webhostapp.com/paypal4/newfile1.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" >
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://infrangible-discoun.000webhostapp.com/paypal4/newfile1.php">  
        <input type="submit" value="PayPal">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Una cosa a entender antes de responderte es que un formulario recoje una peticion, no varias peticiones, por lo que en tu form en `action` siempre ira a esa linea. Ahora una solucion que se me ocurre es que trabajes el boton `eliminar` de forma independiente sin el `submit`, sino trabajalo con un `onclick` y que por separado envie su propia peticion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu formulario esa es la instrucción que le estás dando:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

La solucion que le encuentro es la siguiente:

JavaScript:

```
var formulario = document.getElementById('miform');

document.getElementById('paypal').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    formulario.setAttribute('action', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscra');
    formulario.submit();
})

document.getElementById('eliminar').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      formulario.setAttribute('action', 'borrar.php');
      formulario.submit();
})
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#" id="miform" method="post">
  <!-- Todo tu formulario -->

  <input type='submit' name='eliminar' id="eliminar" value='Eliminar'>
  <input type="submit" id="paypal" value="PayPal">
</form>
```

Lo que hacemos es que al darle click en Paypal se establezca el action del form en la url de Paypal y lo mismo con el botón de eliminar, pero con la URL 'borrar.php'

Quedo atento a tus dudas, espero te sirva :D

Comment: no me funciona. Ni va a la pagina de paypal ni a la pagina "borrar.php". Ademas le pongo un alert en el eventlistener y no salta el alert.

Comment: @palanganero El Script debe ir al final del documento, por encima de la etiqueta </body> y el 
Scriptt debe ir dentro de las etiquetas <script> </script>

Answer (score 0):

preferi traducir tu script a jquery y añadirlo al principio del documento:

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){    
var formulario=$('#formularioPagar');
    $('#pagar').click(function(){      
    formulario.attr('action', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscra');
    formulario.submit();       
    });
    $('#eliminar').click(function(){
      alert("hola");
    formulario.attr('action', 'borrar.php');
    formulario.submit();        
    });
});
```